# graph weight Visualization incorrect

Tags: tikz-pgf

A picture is worth a thousand words ...

[image]

As you can see, the weight-caption are drawn into the line. Anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=white!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[initial,main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {3};


  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {0.5} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {0.8} (3);


\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Beispiel Pfad} \label{fig:begriffe_4}

\end{figure}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Replace `right` with `auto`

Comment: @user2463728, consider writing a self-answer for this question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Answering per information in the comments.

For the `edge node`s, specifying `right` forced placement of the label to the right of the midpoint of the connecting arrow, which falls on the line itself.

Changing `right` to `auto` for both `edge node`s resolves the issue.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,
    >=stealth,
    shorten >=1pt,
    auto, 
    node distance=3cm,
    thick,
    main node/.style={circle,fill=white!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries,},
  ]

    \node[initial,main node] (1) {1};
    \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {2};
    \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {3};

    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
      (1) edge node [auto] {0.5} (2)
      (2) edge node [auto] {0.8} (3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Beispiel Pfad} \label{fig:begriffe_4}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]